# Is there a way in Matplotlib to plot a function of two variables, y = y(x₀, x₁)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I have a function that takes two inputs as arguments and returns an output based on the two inputs.

The two inputs, *r* and *E* range between 3-14 and 0.05-0.75 respectively and will be used to create some values for inputs based on some intervals.

Each set of the two inputs (*r* and *E*) will generate an output. I want to plot the function based on that data using Python's Matplotlib library.

I have used matplotlib for graphing an input x with output y, but I can't think of a way to plot a function whose output depends equally on two inputs.

Comment: search the site for `plt.contour` and `plt.contourf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most critical point in what you want to do is to understand that Matplotlib requires that the data is organized in a 2D grid, consequently it is convenient that you compute the data exploiting Numpy's ability to operate on multidimensional data structures.

1. compute two 1D arrays with the coordinates of the grid — in the example the grid points are equally spaced but the grids can be also irregular,
2. from the two 1D arrays, using `numpy.meshgrid`, compute two 2D arrays containing, the first the *x₀* coordinates in all the grid points, the second the *x₁* coordinates in all the grid points.
3. using the vector-enabled Numpy's mathematical functions, compute the values of *y* on the grid at once, using the 2D arrays as the *x₀* and *x₁*,
4. plot the contour lines, in black, using a relatively small number of levels to avoid a crowded figure,
5. plot a color-mapped representation of *y*, this time we can use a larger number of levels to have a continuous effect,
6. add the labels on the contour lines (note that we use the object returned by `contour`) and add a colorbar that  explains the values in the figure (note that we use the object returned by `contourf`):

And this is the simple code that implements the lengthy explanation above:

```
In [35]: import numpy as np
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: 
    ...: X0 = np.linspace(3, 14, 111)
    ...: X1 = np.linspace(0.05, 0.75, 71)
    ...: x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(X0, X1)
    ...: y = np.cos(x0-10*x1)*(x0-40*(x1-0.2)**2)
    ...: 
    ...: ctr = plt.contour( x0, x1, y, levels=4, colors='k')
    ...: fil = plt.contourf(x0, x1, y, levels=60)
    ...: plt.clabel(ctr)
    ...: plt.colorbar(fil)
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image: plot of a function of two variables using contours and colormap]

---

Another possibility is to make a 3D plot, using the `plot_surface` method. The `plot_surface` method is only available for Axes that have been instantiated using the keyword argument `projection='3d'`, so we cannot use the convenience `plt` namespace as in the previous example…

Everything we discussed about the grid is still valid, the signature in terms of requested arguments is the same, `…(x0, x1, y, **kwd_args)`, the example is hence straightforward if you followed the previous one, but it uses a couple of tricks

1. when you plot a surface on your computer, you can rotate the graph at will to look at the data from different points of view, when you publish the figure in a traditional way (e.g., on Stack Overflow) you lose this interactivity. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57286929/2749397) introduced me to a technique that alleviates the problem.
2. if you want to place a colormap aside of the multiple subplots, it can be difficult to place it correctly, difficult unless you have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795901/2749397)…

Again, the code and its product

```
In [41]: fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,6),
    ...:                          constrained_layout=True,
    ...:                          subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
    ...: surfs = [ax.view_init(elev=10.+i*10, azim=25+i*25) or
    ...:          ax.plot_surface(x0, x1, y, cmap='viridis')
    ...:              for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat)]
    ...: fig.colorbar(surfs[0], ax=axes.flat, aspect=50);

In [42]:
```

[image: surface plots of a function of two variables]